# TypeScript error when passing parameters between functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

This pattern is throwing the TypeScript error:

> Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'string[] | number[]'

```
function foo(value: string | number) {
  return bar([value]); // <- TypeScript error
}

function bar(valueList: string[] | number[]) {
  ..does something...
}
```

I understand this is because TypeScript compiler will see this as an array with a mix of strings and numbers.

Is there a type-safe way to accomplish this? I can only think to cast to `any[]` which feels bad:

```
function foo(value: string | number) {
  const valueList: any[] = [value];
  return bar(valueList);
}
```

Comment: Did you notice the difference between string and string[] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is [*declaration merging*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html); define two separate interfaces for your function (see [function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types)), then a single implementation of it:

```
interface Foo {
    (value: string): void;
}

interface Foo {
    (value: number): void;
}

const foo: Foo = function (value) {
  return bar([value]);
}
```

This will keep the two types separate, as only one of those interfaces can be called through at any given time.

Comment: Is there a reason, you're not using something like this: function foo(value: string);
function foo(value: number);
function foo(value: any) {
    return bar([value]);
}

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I did not know you could do it like that!

Comment: Thx, wasn't sure if it was deprecated or the separate interface has other benefits ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is inspired by jonrsharpe's answer but instead of using a separate interface, it uses function overloading.

Function overloads allow us to specify multiple signatures for a single implementation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

```
function foo(value: string);
function foo(value: number);
function foo(value: any) {
    return bar([value]);
}

function bar(valueList: number[] | string[]) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is good (I've upvoted it), but I would personally go with

```
return bar([value] as string[] | number[]);
```

especially, if I am short on time. This does not mean that it's wrong or hackish, you are just hinting to silly (in this case) Typescript a bit.

P.S. As @paleo mentioned, this is not completely type-safe.

Comment: Your solution is not really type-safe because you could write: `function foo(value: string | boolean) {
  return bar([value] as string[] | number[]);
}
` (with a boolean value as parameter).

Comment: Personally, I avoid overly verbose solutions. I would just use a `as any` until a next version of TypeScript correctly infers this case. Maybe also opening a ticket on GitHub. But I don't propose this answer for fear of downvotes. ;)

Comment: @Paleo agree on everything.